# How to resolve unhandled error in Flume while extracting Tweets

Tags: twitter, flume, unhandled

Receiving Unhandled error - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProviders$FileWatchRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java

I am trying to extract Tweets into HDFS using Flume. But getting org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatchRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java) Unhandled Error
Configuration,  Env.Sh file and .bashrc file details are included in the attached file. File also aontains the Twitter4j version (4j.0
Please have a look and suggest the Resolution.
[DETAILS ATTACHED....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ5Rp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same error with Flume-1.6 version. In flume.conf, update Twitter source type as below:

```
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
```

I didn't use flume-sources-1.0.SNAPSHOT.jar

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dossani  This got resolved after I replace org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource with com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource. Snapshot used and rest everything still remains same.